# Ajax syntax error in an HTML page

Tags: ajax, html

Good evening,

I have been trying to implement this example on an html page. If I look at the IE debugger, it says that I have a syntax error on line 11 (*var arr, i;*). Maybe, do you have an idea what I did wrong in my script?

Many thanks for stopping on my question and your time.

Best wishes,
Laurent

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>home</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/date_time.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle_day.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(
var arr, i;
$.ajax({
method: "GET",
url: "json.php",
dataType: "json"
}).done(function( data ) {
arr = $.parseJSON(data);
i = 0;
$(':checkbox').each(function(){
    this.checked = arr[i++];  //assuming ajax file returned boolean values  in json array.
 });
}));
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Truck"> I have a truck<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you'll need to include the jQuery library. See [How jQuery Works](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I forgot to include the JQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include your code in a callback function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var arr, i;
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "json.php",
      dataType: "json"
    }).done(function( data ) {
      arr = $.parseJSON(data);
      i = 0;
      $(':checkbox').each(function(){
          this.checked = arr[i++];  
       });
      })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it says that '$' is undefined. Is it normal?

Comment: You need to include jQuery library  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`